# Binding the same model variable to radio buttons and input-text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like manage with AngularJS UI which allows to pick one of the options (displayed as radio buttons group) or a custom value typed in a input-text.

It should look like:
http://jsbin.com/foyujali/7/edit

Here is the code that you can see also in the link below:

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="tagsApp" ng-controller="TagsCtrl">
  <input type="radio" id="conversion_type_sale" ng-model="tag.conversion_type" value="sale"/>
  <label for=conversion_type_sale>Sale</label>

  <input type="radio" id="conversion_type_lead" ng-model="tag.conversion_type" value="lead"/>
  <label for=conversion_type_lead>Lead</label>

  <input type="radio" id="conversion_type_custom" ng-model="tag.conversion_type" value="{{tag.conversion_type_custom_value}}"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Custom"  ng-model="tag.conversion_type_custom_value" id="conversion_type_custom_value"/>
  <p>
    The choosen conversion type is: <strong>{{tag.conversion_type}}</strong>
  </p>  
</div>
```

And JS:

```
angular.module('tagsApp', []).
controller('TagsCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.tag = {conversion_type: 'lead'};
});
```

I would prefer not to use ngChange directive so I just bind the `value` or `ng-value` (I tried both) to the model of the input-text. It doesn't work properly this way, but I suppose there is an elegant AngularJS solution. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

**P.S. Just to clarify - I want the following functionality: http://jsbin.com/foyujali/10/edit but I want to avoid using ngChange directive.**

Comment: I wouldn't use the same variable to determine both the custom state and the value itself but if you REALLY wanted to do that then you would have to create your own directive to do the logic for having a "custom radio" button with a text input

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately if I bind the same model to the input-text - it doesn't provide me the desired functionality. Please check the link I've put in the P.S.

Answer (score 2):

**This is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/colares/shcv8e1h/2/**

**Explaning the behavior**

- By focusing on the text field, the radio on the left is selected and chosen value is updated regarding the value of the text field;
- By focusing on radio on the left of the text field, the chosen value is updated according to what is in the text field as well;
- By changing the value of the text field, the chosen value is also updated;
- Finally, by focusing on any other label or radio, the custom value remains, while the chosen value is update regarding the selected option.

To do so, I had to use a few more things in custom option input:

- [ng-focus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus): when I click on the text field, it updates the chosen value regarding the text field;
- [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange): as I update the text field, the final value is also updated;
- [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel): to store the auxiliar variable `customColor`, which remains regardless of the selected value.
- Remember, the [ng-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) is used to set the value of the radio (or an `<option>`) from a given expression when we select it. This makes the radio and input text "bound", because they have the same value.

Comment: I like this solution, but there's a minor issue. If you type in one of the default values (e.g. red), notice that the default "red" is selected. Now click to "green" and click back to either "other" or "red" and notice the wrong radio btn is activated

Answer (score 1):

You could use $scope.$watch and look for the change in your controller like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/2R6aN/

```
var app = angular.module('tagsApp',[]);
app.controller('TagsCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.tag = {conversion_type: 'lead'};
    $scope.$watch('conversion_type_custom_value',function(new_val) {
        if (new_val) {
            $scope.tag.conversion_type = new_val;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. From my point of view it's a more elegant version of the ngChange code I've put in P.S. in the question. I was curious if there is a way to achieve the desired functionality just via attributes (without coding the binding callback).

Comment: You could with directives but I think it would be a bit overkill unless you were going to use the same directive in several places.

Answer (score 0):

$watch is best option. Also, Instead of using modelName in 1st parameter of $watch, you can create your own stuff(eg. watching length of input box) and do desired action on it with second parameter.