# How to create a "other" or "catch all" radio button?

Tags: angularjs

Suppose I want to present a few default options for the user but also want to allow them to enter their own value.

e.g.

```
Please select one of the following:
[ ] apple
[ ] pear
[ ] other: ___________
```

I want it so that if "other" is selected, then the input field that follows should be enabled and allow typing.

Html might look like this:

```
    <input type="radio"
             name="fruit"
             ng-model="fruit"
             value="apple"
             > apple
    <input type="radio"
             name="fruit"
             ng-model="fruit"
             value="pear"
             > pear
      <input type="radio"
             name="fruit"
             ng-model="???"
             value="???"
             > Other:
    <input type="text"
             class="form-control"
             ng-model="fruit"
             ng-disabled="???">
```

What would you do here?

I had an implementation where the default options trigger an action on ng-change such that it changed a $scope.isOther to true, which would enable the input box and check the other radio box like so

```
    <input type="radio"
             name="fruit"
             ng-model="fruit"
             value="apple"
             ng-change="isOther=true"
             > apple
    <input type="radio"
             name="fruit"
             ng-model="fruit"
             value="pear"
             ng-change="isOther=true"
             > pear
      <input type="radio"
             name="fruit"
             ng-model="isOther"
             ng-change="fruit=null"
             value="true"
             > Other:
    <input type="text"
             class="form-control"
             ng-model="fruit"
             ng-disabled="!isOther">
```

That sort of works. But when I reload the page/data, if I have an "other" value entered, it doesn't know to automatically check "other", although my "other" value is in the input box. I could write some more code change the isOther value when I'm loading the data but I'm wondering if I'm even going about this the right way or whether there's a "catch all" that allows a radio box to be checked if it doesn't match any other values.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615610/binding-the-same-model-variable-to-radio-buttons-and-input-text

Comment: almost. using a custom var and ng-focus is a new way of looking at it. But there's an issue where if you type a default value (e.g. "apple" or "red") in "other", then it selects the default value. That's a problem if I want to continue typing "appleorange" because when the default option is selected, the "other" input is disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a perfect answer, but I ended up doing it this way

html:

```
<div id='main' ng-app='myApp'>
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="f in fruits track by $index">
      <input type="radio" name="fruit" ng-model="fruit.value" ng-value="f" ng-change="disableOther()"> {{f}}
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="otherfruit" ng-change="fruit.value=null" ng-model="isOther" ng-value="true"> Other:
    <input type="text" ng-model="fruit.value" ng-change="checkOther()" ng-class="{'disabled-input':isStandardFruit()}">
    <br> fruit = {{fruit.value}}
  </form>
</div>
```

code:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myapp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'plum', 'pear'];
    $scope.fruit = {value:'orange'};  

  $scope.isStandardFruit = function() {
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.fruits.length; i++) {
      if( $scope.fruits[i] == $scope.fruit.value ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

    $scope.disableOther = function() {
      $scope.isOther = false;
    }

    $scope.checkOther = function() {
      if( !$scope.isStandardFruit() ) {
        $scope.isOther = true;
      }
    }  
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6on7ggu/1/)

The one drawback is that if you type a standard fruit into the "other" input box, then it selects multiple radio buttons. I could uncheck the "other" button but then you couldn't type a fruit that contained the standard fruit as a prefix (e.g. you wouldn't be able to type "apple pear")

If anyone can come up with a better answer, I will change my vote and answers

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myapp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'plum', 'pear'];
 $scope.fruit = {selectedOption: 'orange'};  
  
  $scope.isDisabled = function() {
    if (_.contains($scope.fruits, $scope.fruit.selectedOption)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  $scope.add = function() {
   if($scope.x !== undefined && $scope.x !== '') {
     $scope.fruits.push($scope.x);
     $scope.fruit.selectedOption = $scope.x;
      $scope.x = '';
    }    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id='main' ng-app='myApp'>
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="f in fruits track by $index">
      <input type="radio" name="fruit" ng-model="fruit.selectedOption" value={{f}}> {{f}}
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" ng-model="fruit.selectedOption" value="other"> Other:
    <input type="text" ng-model="x" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" ng-blur="add()">
    <br> fruit = {{fruit.selectedOption}}
  </form>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hd84335/hp7bzfcx/)

Comment: This is an interesting solution--adding extra options in the Other input. But I can't keep adding options so not exactly the answer I was looking for. However, you get an upvote!

Comment: there was a bug inside my script, here it is now updated!